# How to debug a Google Drive API 500 Error on Wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, debugging, google-drive-api

I would like some help on how to debug a 500 error that comes from an AJAX request.

I've built a Wordpress plugin that creates a folder and uploads files to Google Drive. It was working great on one Wordpress site, but when I installed it on this second one it returns a 500 error on the moment of the folder creation.

**Here's some information:**

- The function that creates the folder is called through AJAX.
- The credentials and the auth are working fine.
- All the code works until it hits this: `$folderId = $service->files->create($folder);`
- No error is displayed on the Wordpress error log.

AJAX request code:

```
return $.ajax({
           url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
           type: 'GET',
           contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           data: {
             action: 'create_folder',
             data: $('form[data-step] input, form[data-step] select').map(function () {
                var value = $(this).val().trim();
                
                return( value == "" || value == 'State*' || value == 'State of Formation' ) ? null : this;
            }).serialize()
           },
           success: function(dataUrl){
             assignUrl(dataUrl);
             
           },
          });
```

I would like some help on how to debug this. Since it's called using AJAX I can't see more information about the error so I can track it. Which is the better way to debug it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please add the code of your AJAX request to Google Drive API?

Comment: AJAX code added

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn on debug mode. It may show the error on screen.

   ```
   define('WP_DEBUG', true);
   ```
2. Repeat the error
3. In `wp-content` there should be the debug.log with error